# How to fix black lines on a model's hair?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
^previous render i have done

I'm like super confused how to fix this, it's never done this before & I'm on alpha hashed and also tried max transparency bounces on light paths. I'd love to know what's causing this! (I am fairly new to blender so please bare with)

Comment: hello please show your material settings, maybe even share the hair object?

Comment: Hi, it is a dae so I don't think I'd be able to share the object as I ripped the model and imported as a dae (correct me if I'm wrong I don't know a thing about blender lol) where can I find the material settings sorry?

Comment: The material set up can be seen in the Shader Editor. It seems you are using Eevee as render engine. Can you please edit your question and show the material of the hair and - as you have mentioned that it previously worked  - a screenshot from a previous render.

Comment: Okay I'll edit my post now, I am using cycles and the hair is apart of the whole model so it's not separate if that makes sense since I imported the entire dae from a ripper program.

Comment: The best would be to share the hair object itself, make sure that you've packed your image (FIle > External Data > Pack Resources)